# How to referencing my raw txt file with FileReader?

Tags: java, android, arrays, multidimensional-array, java.util.scanner

I'm trying to teach myself how to read a raw resources text file into a multidimensional array without much luck thus far.  Here is the raw text file:

```
ken todd
stuart brian
bob stewart
orange apple

green red
```

The code I have is shown below.

```
   public void LoadFromFile (){

        //  int fileId = (getResources().getIdentifier("text_file",
         //        "raw", getPackageName()));
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(new FileReader(R.raw.text_file);
        // initialises the scanner to read the text_file

        String[][] entries = new String[6][2];
        // creates a 2d array with 6 rows and 2 columns.

        int i = 0;
        while (scan.hasNextLine()) {
            entries[i] = scan.nextLine().split("\\s+");
            i++;
        }
        //loops through the file and splits on a space

        for (int row = 0; row < entries.length; row++) {
            for (int col = 0; col < entries[0].length; col++) {
                if (entries[row][col] != null) {
                    System.out.print(entries[row][col] + " ");
                }
            }
            if (entries[row][0] != null) {
                System.out.print("\n");
            }
        }
        //prints the contents of the array that are not "null"
    }
```

I'm getting an error on the scanner line. Specifically FileReader(R.raw.text_file) I get

> Cannot resolve constructor 'FileReader(int)'

Obviously FileReader is looking for an int and i tried to do that by putting the file ID int an int variable and then using the int variable in the FileReader but that didn't work either.

```
int fileId = (getResources().getIdentifier("text_file", 
        "raw", getPackageName()));
Scanner scan = new Scanner(new FileReader(fileId);
```

It gave me the same error

> Cannot resolve constructor 'FileReader(int)'

What am I doing wrong here?  Anybody got tips in how to get a file put into an array?

Cheers

Airfix

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to the guidance of Doug Stevenson I managed to get the code correct to read a file into an array. I've got a couple of other details that I need to sort out such as making the array the correct size for the text file (rather than hard coding) and dealing with a blank line in the text file.

In the mean time here is the working code to load a text file into an array:

```
public void TextFileReader (){

        String[][] textFileData = new String[5][2];

        InputStreamReader InputSR = null;
        BufferedReader BufferedRdr = null;
        String thisLine = null;

        InputSR = new InputStreamReader(getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.text_file));
        BufferedRdr = new BufferedReader(InputSR);

        try {
            // open input stream text_file for reading purpose.
            int i = 0;
            while ((thisLine = BufferedRdr.readLine()) != null) {
                String[] parts = thisLine.split(" ");
                textFileData[i][0] = parts[0];
                textFileData[i][1] = parts[1];
                Log.v("String Array"+i+"0", String.valueOf(textFileData[i][0]));
                Log.v("String Array"+i+"1", String.valueOf(textFileData[i][1]));
                i = i +1;
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

You can read raw resources with [openRawResource(int)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Resources.html#openRawResource(int)).  That will give you an InputStream that you can wrap with an [InputStreamReader](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/InputStreamReader.html), then wrap with a [BufferedReader](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/BufferedReader.html).  You can then use [readLine()](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/BufferedReader.html#readLine%28%29) on that BufferedReader to get lines out of it.

Comment: Doug, I'm getting close to getting a solution using your help. See my gist here. https://gist.github.com/Airfixed/799e784696b0a60c5423d347bf33a341 However if there is a blank line in teh txt file it doesn't work.  How do I account for a blank line?

Answer (score 0):

A resource is a file **on your development machine**. It is not a file on the Android device. You cannot use a `FileReader` to access it. Use `getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.text_file)` (called on a `Context`) to get an `InputStream` on the resource.